# Converting mysql DB empty schema to sqlite DB schema

Tags: mysql, sqlite, xamarin

I'm having mysql empty schema like abc.sql(with out data, but it is having create, create trigger, auto increment and it is having around 100 tables)  now i need to convert that same to sqlite schema like sample.sql.

Please help me... Thanks in advance

Regards,
Shyam

Comment: Without any code, your question is too broad.  With code, your question is also probably too broad, but if you show us some particular MySQL code, maybe we can make suggestions on how to port it over to SQLite.

Comment: Start by reading https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html and https://www.sqlite.org/quirks.html